# Unclear why functions from Data.Ratio are not exposed and how to work around

Tags: haskell, module, numeric, module.exports

I am implementing an algorithm using `Data.Ratio` ([convergents of continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents)).
However, I encounter two obstacles:

- The algorithm starts with the fraction `1%0` - but this throws a zero denominator exception.
- I would like to pattern match the constructor `a :% b`

I was exploring on [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html). An in particular the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#Rational) seems to be using exactly these features (e.g. defining `infinity   = 1 :% 0`, or pattern matching for `numerator`).

As beginner, I am  also confused where it is determined that `(%)`, `numerator` and such are exposed to me, but not `infinity` and `(:%)`.

I have already made a dirty workaround using a tuple of integers, but it seems  silly to reinvent the wheel about something so trivial.
Also would be nice to learn how read the source which functions are exposed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They aren't exported precisely to prevent people from doing stuff like this. See, the type

```
data Ratio a = a:%a
```

contains *too many values*. In particular, e.g. `2/6` and `3/9` are actually *the same number* in ℚ and both represented by `1:%3`. Thus, `2:%6` is in fact an *illegal* value, and so is, sure enough, `1:%0`. *Or* it might be legal but all functions know how to treat them so `2:%6` is for all observable means equal to `1:%3` – I don't in fact know which of these options GHC chooses, but at any rate it's an implementation detail and could change in future releases without notice.

If the library authors themselves use such values for e.g. optimisation tricks that's one thing – they have after all full control over any algorithmic details and any undefined behaviour that could arise. But if *users* got to construct such values, it would result in brittle code.

So – if you find yourself starting an algorithm with `1/0`, then you should indeed not use `Ratio` at all there but simply store numerator and denominator in a plain tuple, which has no such issues, and only make the final result a `Ratio` with `%`.

Comment: I agree with what you write. It's just confusing to me when reading the linked code. The definition for `infinity` is never used again - so I doubt it's for optimization, also why put it in the source if this becomes an invalid value? Enhancing my confusion is that I don't understand where is marked which functions will be exposed.

Comment: It's never used again? Weird; then it should actually be removed. I suspect they used it at some point for something, but then found out it was a bad idea to do it with “infinity” so did it different but never got around to removing the definition `infinity = 1/0`.

Comment: What is exported is always marked in the _module head_. In this case, [`module Data.Ratio (Ratio, Rational, (%), ...) where`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Ratio.html). Note also that the underlying module `GHC.Real` where this stuff is originally defined _does_ export `:%` and `infinity`, but that module is marked `Stability   :  internal` whereas `Data.Ratio` is `Stability   :  stable`.

Comment: That's nice in theory, but  performance characteristics of different representations are so different that it doesn't seem realistic for `base` to ever switch—some things would get a lot faster, but others would get unacceptably slower.

Comment: There was a suggestion (about 30 years ago) to allow the 1%0, -1%0 and 0%0 for infinity, -infinity and NaN.  But the idea was rejected by Joe Fasel (who wrote all the original libraries for Haskell) because then Rational would no longer be a field.  It would be quite useful sometimes, though.